# Feller vol. I, probability of 'r' successes in binomial process

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This question is about the calculation of probability of at least 'r' successes in a binomial process given in the page 151 of feller:intro to probability:vol-1. Before deriving equation 3.5, text says the quantity

$$b\left(r;n,p\right)$$

(which is the probability of r successes out of n with success probability p) is at most

$$1/\left(r-np\right).$$
(assuming r>np, which is the case for the right tail of the binomial distribution)
I need help understanding how this is so. I just want to see a short mathematical proof of that.

Comment: Are you sure $1/(r - np)$ is correct? Let's see what happens if $n = 10$, $p = 0.8$ and $r = 1$. Now $1/(r - np) < 0$!

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is assumed in the text that r>np. That is the above relation is for the right tail of the binomial distribution.